# Different authentication cookies for the same domain

Tags: .net, authentication

I'm using .net 4.

We have a website that has login for users and login for admin

for example:

- `www.mysite.com` this is where the users login;
- `www.mysite.com/admin` this is where our support team logs in;

The problem is that the Authentication cookie is shared between the folders (naturally)

How can i supply a login for our admin users that doesn't apply to the site the users use?

My Authentication code:

```
public static void SetAuthenticationTicket(string userName, string userRole, string isPersistent)
    {
        Boolean defaultPresistant = false;
        Boolean bPresistent = Boolean.TryParse(isPersistent, out defaultPresistant);
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
                                                userName, 
                                                DateTime.Now, 
                                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                                                bPresistent, 
                                                "Role=" + userRole,
                                                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Can I add some parameter to create two distinct login sessions?

Comment: No one could answer this question??